# In spring Oauth 2 authorization server Implementation , how to return an authorization code after user sign up

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

Normally ,the client redirect to Oauth server ,with client id

```
http://localhost:8181/sparklr2/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=tonr-with-redirect&state=xyz
```

the login page is displayed ,after proper credentials are received and authenticated ,confirmation is not call back done to client with authorization code

```
http://localhost:9090/tonr2/sparklr/redirect?code=gm4XN3&state=xyz
```

If the user is not registered and sign up need to be done ,then how to generate a authorization code after sign up with out login

Comment: Which OAuth provider are you targetting?

Comment: I am building my own oauth provider using spring oauth,i referred this following code for building my authorization server  [Doc reference](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)  [Code Reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a general question for Spring security, what you want is a login flow which supports signup and generates a complete authentication at the end of the signup flow.

So you will have to create a custom login form flow that offers signup and then completes the authentication at the end of the signup flow.

If you do this properly Spring oauth should take over and continue the redirect flow just as if you signed on the normal way.